# creating a new instance of a type in scala

Tags: scala, types

If I have a class C defined as

```
class C[A]
```

is there any way to create a new instance of `A` within C? Something like

```
class C[A] {
  def f(): A = new A()
}
```

I understand that, if this were possible, you'd probably have to specify the constructor arguments somewhere, and that's fine.

If it's not possible, are there any design patterns for dealing with the sort of situation where you'd like to create a new instance of a type?

Comment: And what do you suggest happens if the concrete type does not have a (parameterless) construcutor?

Comment: Ideally, you could specify this in the type parameter. So I could define C as `class C[A(String, String)]` or something. Then I'd have to call A with two String arguments.

Comment: @Raphael No, but `class C[(String, String), A]` would be.  It's pretty straightforward to extend my approach below to pass some (or all) of the constructor arguments into the `make` method by making use of a second type parameter.

Comment: But still, one definition of C would only work for one particular constructor signature. That was my point.

Comment: @Raphael Not so. `class C[Args, T](implicit e: Makeable[Args, T]) { ... }`.  Each Makeable instance would just destructure the Args type as necessary to invoke the correct constructor.

Comment: Yea, your "hack" works. I was relating to the original question. That's why I commented here and not on your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a type class to abstract instantiation:

```
trait Makeable[T] {
   def make: T
}

class C[T: Makeable] {
   def f(): T = implicitly[Makeable[T]].make
}
```

For example,

```
implicit object StringIsMakeable extends Makeable[String] {
   def make: String = "a string"
}

val c = new C[String]
c.f // == "a string"
```

When you instantiate C, you'll need to provide, explicitly or implicitly, a Makeable that will act as a factory of the appropriate type.  That factory, of course, would be responsible for supplying any constructor arguments when it invokes the constructor.

Alternatively, you could use a Manifest, but be warned that this approach relies on reflection and is not type safe:

```
class C[T: Manifest] {
   def f(): T = manifest[T].erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

For completeness, you can also easily extend this approach to pass some or all of the constructor parameters in to the make method:

```
trait Makeable[Args, T] { def make(a: Args): T }

class C[Args, T](implicit e: Makeable[Args, T]) {
   def f(a: Args): T = e.make(a)
}

// some examples
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String)

implicit val personFactory1 = new Makeable[(String, String), Person] {
   def make(a: (String, String)): Person = Person(a._1, a._2)
}
implicit val personFactory2 = new Makeable[String, Person] {
   def make(a: String): Person = Person(a, "Smith")
}

val c1 = new C[String, Person]
c1.f("Joe") // returns Person("Joe", "Smith")

val c2 = new C[(String, String), Person]
c2.f("John", "Smith") // returns Person("John", "Smith")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can demand an implicit parameter, like so:

```
class A[T](implicit newT : T) { 
  val t = newT 
}
```

All you need then is to have an implicit factory of the desired type in scope when you instanciate `A`, e.g. the following works:

```
implicit def newSeq[T] = Seq[T]()                
val a = new A[Seq[String]]
```

As shown by:

```
scala> a.t
res22: Seq[String] = List()
```

Answer (score 1):

The same as @Raphael's answer with a case class's `apply` method:

```
class Container[A](contained: A)
case class Person(name: String)
case class PersonContainer(person: Person) extends Container[Person](person)
implicit def _ = PersonContainer.apply _

class Creator {
  def deserializeAndPackage[A, B <: Container[A]](data: Array[Byte])
                           (implicit containerCreator: (A => B)): B = {
    val p = /* deserialize data as type of A */
    containerCreator(p)
  }
}
```